# My code is looping the wrong section of code

Tags: java

For some reason when I write "retry", it simply prompts me again for if I would like to retry or not. How can I solve this issue?

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinFlip {

  public static void main (String[]args)throws InterruptedException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numloop;
    int x = 0;
    String choice;
    Boolean bool = true;
    Boolean bool2 = true;


    while (bool=true){
       x=0;
       System.out.println("How Many Coins Would You Like To Flip?");
       numloop = sc.nextInt();

      if (numloop == 13 || (numloop == 5 || (numloop == 8 || (numloop == 666)))) {
         System.out.println("ILLUMINATI CONFIRMED ??????");
         System.out.println();
      }

       System.out.println("Flipping Coin(s)...");
       System.out.println();

      while (x<numloop) {

         int rng = (int)(Math.random()*10+1);

         if (rng <= 5) {
            System.out.println("You Flipped Heads");
         }

        else {
            System.out.println("You Flipped Tails");
         }

        x=x+1;
      }
      while (bool2=true) {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Would You Like To 'Quit' Or 'Retry'?");
        choice = scan.nextLine();

        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) {
          System.out.println ("Have A Nice Day");
          System.out.println ("Quitting Interactions...");
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          System.exit(0);
        }

        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Retry")) {
          bool=true;
          bool2=false;
        }

        else {
          System.out.println("That Was An Invalid Answer");
          bool=false;
          bool2=true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can solve this issue by using some of these [debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 3):

You need a "==" instead of "=" in your while loops. You're setting bool2 to true every time instead of checking it's value.

Comment: When I do that, if i write "Retry" it loops properly but then after flipping the coins again, it asks right away "How Many Coins Would You Like To Flip?" rather than asking "Quit or Retry?"

Comment: It went back to the outer loop when you exited the final loop.

Comment: @BerkleyLamb How do I stop it from doing that?

Comment: I guess, it depends on what you intend to do?   Do you only want to ask how many coins once?  then pull that part out of the outermost loop.  you may need another tier if you just want to re-roll the same number of coins

Comment: @BerkleyLamb I would like that to be looped but only if they select retry again, not directly after it flipping the coins

Answer (score 1):

You have written the conditions of the while loops wrongly. `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison. You should write `==` instead of `=` otherwise you are assigning true to the bool every time.

Furthermore, it is a good practice to reverse the syntax i.e. put the constant on the left: `true == bool` to prevent such typos, since the compiler will generate an error if you mistype `true = bool`.

Comment: could you please suggest edits to get it running properly? I have tried re doing my loops but I still get issues

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to get the option "Quit or Retry?" instead of "How Many Coins Would You Like To Flip?" you should be writing them in separate loops. The reason you are getting "How Many Coins Would You Like To Flip?" after retry is because you have set bool2=false in retry loop. With your existing logic "Quit or Retry?" will never be reached after retry, as bool2 is not set to true in the while Loop.

Comment: When i remove it from the retry loop, it continuously loop "Quit or Retry" could you please suggest the correct changes

Comment: retain your logic and set bool2 to false in the "Quit" loop instead of "Retry" loop.